# WPF: On action set background color relative to current color

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, treeview

I have a custom WPF `TreeView`. In there a `TreeViewItem` has a background color depending on its type. I take that information from the `TreeViewItem.Name` and used a trigger as you can see below.

Now when I select or hover over an element in the `TreeView` I want the element to keep its color but be a little more brighter. Currently as shown below I just set the same color for all elements.

How to change that code to make the hovering color relative to the one the element has, no matter which it is?

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">                                
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.Name" Value="TypeA">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#8BADC5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.Name" Value="TypeB">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFC3AF"/>
                            </Trigger>


                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A5243D"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A5243D"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#A5243D"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Can you use the ColorLuminence method contained in this article: [How to Calculate Lighter or Darker Hex Colors in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/)?

Comment: No, Javascript has nothing to do with WPF. I don't ask how to calculate a brigther color. That is the easy part. It is how to apply it into WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with a value converter.

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is SolidColorBrush) {
            // return the calculated new SolidColorBrush
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in xaml resource part:

```
<ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter/>
```

and in xaml body:

```
<Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose an extended version of mami's suggestion where is is easier to formulate the IsMouseOver etc. triggers. It consists of:

- a multi value converter to calculate the background brush to be used from the base value and some transformation parameter
- an attached property to hold the transformation parameter(s)
- in XAML, a multi-binding

As a simple example, suppose the color to use shall be calculated by Color.Multiply with a factor determined by the IsMouseOver etc. states.

The multi value converter:

```
public class MultiplyColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var baseColor = ((SolidColorBrush)values[0]).Color;
        var factor = (float)values[1];
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.Multiply(baseColor, factor));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The transformation parameter attached property:

```
public class ColorTransform
{
    public static float GetFactor(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (float)obj.GetValue(FactorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFactor(DependencyObject obj, float value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FactorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Factor", typeof(float), typeof(ColorTransform), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0F,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
}
```

The XAML:

```
<local:MultiplyColorConverter x:Key="MultiplyColorConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="Bd">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource MultiplyColorConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="BaseColor" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:ColorTransform.Factor)" Mode="OneWay"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="local:ColorTransform.Factor" Value="0.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="local:ColorTransform.Factor" Value="0.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="local:ColorTransform.Factor" Value="0.3"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```